# Case statement for two different strings?

Tags: regex, bash, case-statement

I don't know the best way to form this question, but here's the code I want to work:

```
case $MESSAGE in
    ?Trcx!~*PRIVMSG*[${Nick}|${AltNick}]*[nN][mM]ap*)
       echo "Some Code";;
     *)
       echo "Some Other Code";;
esac
```

How would I make it work?  The part that is not working is the [${Nick}|${AltNick}] I want the expression to be valid for both the $Nick and $AltNick var.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash glob patterns are [documented here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching).
You want this: `@(patt1|patt2)`.
Note the `extglob` shell option must be enabled.

```
shopt -s extglob
case $MESSAGE in
    ?Trcx!~*PRIVMSG*@(${Nick}|${AltNick})*[nN][mM]ap*)
       echo "Some Code";;
     *)
       echo "Some Other Code";;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

In glob patterns, without Bash's "extglob" feature, you cannot group a subpattern with parentheses - and certainly not with square brackets. The Bourne-compatible way is to split into two distinct patterns.

```
case $MESSAGE in
  ?Trcx!~*PRIVMSG*${Nick}*[nN][mM]ap* |
  ?Trcx!~*PRIVMSG*${AltNick}*[nN][mM]ap*)
    echo "Some Code";;
  *)
    echo "Some Other Code";;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash performs case pattern matching just like filename matching, not regular expression matching.  If that's what you want, then problem solved.

However, if you want a regular expression match, perhaps you could try the [[ expression ]] compound command to achieve your goals, which offers the =~ operator for regular expression matching.

```
#!/bin/bash

regexp="^[a-z]*$"
if [[ $1 =~ $regexp ]] ; then                                                                                                                                                                   
   echo "match"
else
   echo "no match"
fi
```